# How do I edit highlighting for built-in functions for PHP in Notepad++?

Tags: php, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

**Question:** *Can someone tell me where to add, in Notepad++, syntax highlighting for built-in functions in PHP?*

There are a few built-in functions in PHP that Notepad++ does not highlight. One I have noticed is "*real_escape_string*."

The langs.model.xml file includes the words to be highlighted with the languages supported by Notepad++.

The langs.model.xml file is found at
C:\Program Files\Notepad++\langs.model.xml

At the top of that file it says the following:
"*The key words of the supported languages, don't touch them!*"

I edited the file anyway. I included "real_escape_string" within keywords in the PHP section. It did not work. The real_escape_string function was not highlighted.

I cannot find a way to add syntax highlighting for built-in functions from the user interface.

[Under "**Settings -> Preferences**" I have looked at all the options and there is no option to edit syntax highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWxmX.png)

[Under "**Settings -> Style Configurator**" there's no place to edit syntax highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6kUb.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%appdata%/Roaming/Notepad++/langs.xml

Keywords for PHP are located around line 172

Add the keywords that you wish to highlight between the `<keywords>` `<keywords?>` tags then restart notepad++

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I can look into the C: directory and the only file I find is the langs.model.xml. If you open from within Notepad++ it shows the directory path for the langs.xml file. Thanks again.